# how to enable Add Text Tool Using Acrobat reader Add text in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an application for correction with pdf files. so, I have to add some notes on specific location when the user clicks on pdf file.
for show pdf file I am using Pdf Viewer component.
now,
I want to enable editing Pdf file in C# window application.
I am using Acrobat Reader - DC purchase edition.

[image: image1]

Comment: How does ASP.NET relate to this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need

Comment: Acrobat Reader - DC is free.

Comment: not free. I am using paid version for edit PDF

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the documentation about AxAcroPdf in this [manual](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf).

AxAcroPdf section begins at page: 106.

There is a bad-documented function .execCommand() that 'maybe' can help in this work.

You'll find some examples: [here](http://www.codeweblog.com/document-execcommand-function-change/)

```
// Insert a textarea
Document.execCommand ('InsertTextArea', true, "your text here");
```